# Endpoint /tags/tag/media/recent is not showing all related posts

Tags: php, api, tags, instagram, missing-data

I am using the tag-Endpoint without OAuth to get all posts containing the Hasthag "#hierfuereuch". It works and returns nearly all matching posts, except some  of the posts from the account http://instagram.com/antenne1de . This is also the account the client-id is registered to.

This is the API-Call I am doing via PHP: https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/hierfuereuch/media/recent?client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX

This post is in the result-list: http://instagram.com/p/j8JTepLcS-/

But this post is not: http://instagram.com/p/j94msxrcTB/

This is the site where the content should show up: http://www.hierfuereuch.de/

You can also use my testing API which returns JSON.
Get the last 10 posts containing the hashtag #hierfuereuch: http://antenne1.tower5.felixhagspiel.de/api/instagram?tag=true

Does anybody know how to fix this? We also tried posting the exact same Posts (same picture, same caption) with another Instagram-Account and it worked. Is there maybe a Problem related to the Account? The Instgram-supportsite is a joke and unfortunately they canceled direct EMail-Support.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: hmm, interesting, not sure what is going on, may they do not allow series of posts from same user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem was that alot of people accessed the account from different devices and from different applications (I think the access via unofficial applications was the main problem). The instagram-servers then flagged it automatically as suspicious which made it impossible to retrieve feeds via the public search-API. However, if you use your own token you can retrieve the posts from your side. Unfortunately instagram support needs ages to respond and they did not unflag the account when I told them that the behaviour is normal (maybe it is just not possible for the support to unflag an account).

Hope this helps if you ran into the same problem.