# Instagram API /tags/hashtag/media/recent not showing all photos with accesstoken

Tags: php, instagram, instagram-api, hashtag

I am trying to collect all posts with a certain hashtag (#inLombardia365) with the Instagram API and Endpoint. For this I use the access the access token like this:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/inlombardia365/media/recent?access_token={MY_ACCESS_TOKEN}&count=100
```

I will loop through all the posts until a specific date (I know when the first post was added to Instagram with the hashtag so I know when to stop searching). The next_max_id, is used to "paginate" the results. This will bring up (only) 3 posts via de API instead of the added 12 photos that can be found on Instagram within that time frame. (January first 2016, till now). Even when I check the results manually in the API response I can not find the posts so I am quite sure it's  not returned.

For example one of the photos which is never returned in the API response is this Instagram photo: https://www.instagram.com/p/BBuuvTEPJ57/

I found a similar post having the same issues here: 
[Endpoint /tags/tag/media/recent is not showing all related posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21577250/endpoint-tags-tag-media-recent-is-not-showing-all-related-posts)

In the reply it states that the problem could be resolved by using the access token, but in my case that didn't helped.

Is this a problem on my end (where I am doing it wrong) or is this a Instagram API issue?